# Change order item displayed meta key label in WooCommerce admin order pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

Following [Display a product custom field only in WooCommerce Admin single orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65877051/display-a-product-custom-field-only-in-woocommerce-admin-single-orders/65877122?noredirect=1#comment116504080_65877122) answer to my previous question, which:

1. Adds a Custom SKU Field (ArticleID)
2. Saves the Custom SKU (ArticleID) as Hidden Order Item Meta Data
3. Saves the Custom SKU (ArticleID) as Hidden Order Item Meta Data for Manual Orders

How can I change the displayed meta key label `_articleid` on order line items section of the admin single order pages?

Right now it shows the "SKU", the "Variation ID" (for product variations) and the "_articleid".

I'd like to replace displayed "_articleid" with "Article ID" instead.

Any help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will use the following to replace displayed key label `_articleid` with for example 'Article ID' in order items on WooCommerce admin single orders:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_key', 'filter_wc_order_item_display_meta_key', 20, 3 );
function filter_wc_order_item_display_meta_key( $display_key, $meta, $item ) {

    // Change displayed label for specific order item meta key
    if( is_admin() && $item->get_type() === 'line_item' && $meta->key === '_articleid' ) {
        $display_key = __("Article ID", "woocommerce" );
    }
    return $display_key;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Related:

[Change order item custom meta data displayed label and value in WooCommerce Admin orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65892137/change-order-item-custom-meta-data-displayed-label-and-value-in-woocommerce-admi)

Related to this thread:

- [How to show a product custom field (custom SKU) in WooCommerce orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65874654/how-to-show-a-product-custom-field-custom-sku-in-woocommerce-orders)
- [Display a product custom field only in WooCommerce Admin single orders for Manual Orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65892831/display-a-product-custom-field-only-in-woocommerce-admin-single-orders-for-manua)